# pyhamcrest contains matcher for list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, python-unittest, pyhamcrest

Why pyhamcrest is failing *contains()* matcher for list of 2 or more dicts, but works fine with list of 1 dict?

[PyHamcrest contains](http://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/sequence_matchers/#module-hamcrest.library.collection.issequence_containinginorder)

What is the best way to write hamcrest (pyhamcrest) matcher for list of dicts?

First test passed, second failed in this unittest example.

```
import unittest
from hamcrest import contains, assert_that, has_entries

class ContainsTest(unittest.TestCase):

    dict1, dict2 = {"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 1, "b": 2}
    sequence1, sequence2 = list(), list()
    sequence1.append(dict1)
    sequence2.append(dict1)
    sequence2.append(dict2)

    @staticmethod
    def test_sequence():
        assert_that(ContainsTest.sequence1, contains(has_entries({'a': 1, 'b': 2})))
        assert_that(ContainsTest.sequence2, contains(has_entries({'a': 1, 'b': 2})))


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    ContainsTest.test_sequence()
```

Unittest output:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hamcrest/core/assert_that.py", 
line 57, in _assert_match raise AssertionError(description) 
AssertionError:  
Expected: a sequence containing [a dictionary containing {'a': <1>, 'b': <2>}]
but: Not matched: <{'a': 1, 'b': 2}>

Ran 1 test in 0.027s
FAILED (failures=1)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`has_item`](http://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/sequence_matchers/#module-hamcrest.library.collection.issequence_containing), not `contains`.

Somewhat confusingly, PyHamcrest's `contains` isn't a containment check in the sense of the `__contains__` magic method. Its semantics are modeled after the original Hamcrest's [`contains` matcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains(E...)). It's not testing if some element of the list matches the given matcher; it wants a separate matcher for each list element, and it'll apply matchers to corresponding elements of the list. `has_item` is the one that checks if some item matches.

Quoting the [docs](http://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/sequence_matchers/#module-hamcrest.library.collection.issequence_containinginorder):

> Matches if sequence’s elements satisfy a given list of matchers, **in
>   order**.
>
> Parameters:   match1,... – A comma-separated list of matchers.
>   This matcher iterates the evaluated sequence and a given list of matchers,
>   seeing if each element satisfies its **corresponding** matcher.
>
> Any argument that is not a matcher is implicitly wrapped in an
>   equal_to matcher to check for equality.

You've provided one matcher for a list of two elements. PyHamcrest wants two matchers. The second dict isn't getting matched.

Comment: Yes, assert_that(ContainsTest.sequence2, has_items(has_entries({'a': 1, 'b': 2}))) works fine, thank you.